# Xcode 7.1.1 : How to test 3D touch in simulator

Tags: swift2, ios9.1, 3dtouch, xcode7.1.1

I've download sample code for [3D touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ViewControllerPreviews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016546-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). How can 3D touch functionality can be tested in simulator? I'm using Xcode 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Currently 3D touch functionality cannot be presently tested in the simulator, not even with those fancy new pressure sensitive trackpads.

You will need a physical device which supports 3d touch.